# unable to get the data from facebook in codeigniter using hybridauth . Anyone Suggest?

Tags: codeigniter, continuous-integration, facebook-apps, hybridauth, facebook-app-settings

I am using Hybridauth in Codeigniter and not able to get data from Facebook. When I print user_profile I get this response:

```
Hybrid_User_Profile Object(
[identifier] => myid [email] => [emailVerified] => [phone] =>
[address] => [country] => [region] => [city] => [zip] => )
```

Comment: share some more code what have tried till now??

Answer (score 0):

well to get data from facebook you need to pass special permissions and then check what is coming from response